# Как реализовать масштабирование как в Paint на js

Tags: javascript, события

Хочется сделать эффект на JS, чтобы при удерживании <kbd>LMB</kbd> на `.changer` и при перетаскивании его из стороны в сторону менялась ширина `.block`, как  в Paint или Photoshop, есть идея сделать это через событие `mousemove`, но не знаю как реализовать синюю пунктирную рамку как в самом Paint.
Помогите пожалуйста!)

```css
.block {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background: lightgreen;
}

.changer {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #fff;
  left: 500px;
  top: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="changer"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Об этом идёт речь?

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.resize {
  display: block;
  min-width: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  max-width: 100%;
  min-height: 10px;
  height: 100px;
  max-height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  resize: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="resize"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, про css совсем забыл, но есть ли в js событие, например  onresize (?) или нечто подобное? Мне просто нужно будет ещё и canvas внутри .resize масштабировать. Ну, и ещё вопрос - можно ли стилизовать ползунок, за который тащит пользователь, например, скрыв его и добавив ::after?

Comment: Вот как раз в приведённым кодом `.resize()` не работает, есть такой способ - [ссылка](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-resize/examples/resize/)

Comment: Ладно, я уже разобрался, и сляпал свой собственный говнокодик, который работает почти так, как надо, но, к сожалению, не могу понять в чём причина косяков. Поможете? https://codepen.io/Jizzybole/pen/gOrbzwX